# Android - SQLite - update()

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update

So my issue is quite interesting.  I have searched for an answer and unfortunately nothing helps.  Ive been developing an app and have run into a small issue.  Today, a colleague of mine mentioned that the app should allow users to select a specific record from the database and then edit it.  So I added the following code:

```
_dbw.update(TABLE_CHRG_DATA, values, COLUMN_KEY + "=?", new String[] {recordNum});
```

The issue is that instead of updating the record, it adds a new record, which I had thought should not happen with update().

Anyway, I am wondering what the hell is going on here and would very much appreciate some assistance.  I have tried everything I can think of, but the code continues to add a new record, rather than editing the existing record.  I think I just need a second opinion, heh.,

TIA

Brad.

Comment: @MylesBaker - Thanks for the quick reply.  _dbw is a SQLite db.  Here is the code:  final SQLiteDatabase _dbw = this.getWritableDatabase();  .  Ive tried various ways of setting up the line of code from the op, which I guess really shouldnt make any difference.  I have 2 lines of code, that either create a new record, or update an existing record.  During debugging, I can see that it bypasses the insert and does execute the update, but still a whole new record is being created.  Im wondering if it may have something to do with the key thats Im passing but have seen no warnings or errors.

Comment: What is the return value of `_dbw.update`? It should return the integer number of records affected. I'm concerned you may have multiple instances of `_dbw`. Otherwise, you should confirm the `where` clause, `COLUMN_KEY + "=?"`.

Comment: `update()` *cannot* add records (unless you have a triger that does this). Why do you think that there is a new record in the database?

Comment: @CL. - When I count the number of records in the table, it has increased by one.  Also, the record that I write in is very specific, so that I can inspect the data after and verify that the record has been altered.  When I do inspect the data after the update, I see the record that I was altering, in its original state, and also the same record, with the change that I had made.  Then, when I check the position of the cursor, its incremented. I know that this should not happen, which is why Im stumped.  There shouldnt be any triggers as the db is very simple, with just a few tables.

Comment: You say that the code does either an insert or an update. All the evidence you have shown indicates that it is the insert that gets executed.

Comment: @CL. - Thanks for the quick reply.  I have stepped through the code while debugging and verified that it is definitely the update that gets executed.  Just tried again with the insert commented out, so definitely not the insert being executed.

Comment: @MylesBaker - The return value is 1.  So it seems to be doing what its supposed to, heh.  ugh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...  This is why one should occasionally sleep, Lol.  After going through the code again, I found the issue.  For a user to edit an existing record, they navigate through the records and then edit the one they want.  To do this, I use the position of the cursor, which turns out, starts at 0.  The ids in the database however, start at 1..  So it WAS doing the update, just on the wrong record.  I now just increment recordNum by 1 and its good to go.  Just ran through another quick test and she is working as expected.

Thanks again all!

Brad.